# Photos doesn't display on iis when using <asp:image>

Tags: asp.net, image, iis, relative-path

I've a problem when I try to display a photo using the asp:image tag.

I work on Visual Studio 2008, it displays the photo in VS but not on the IIS.
If I put my path in the network, it works.

I try with absolute, relative and virtual path.

Of course, I use the imageUrl and not src ...

Now, I have no idea, so I need helps please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used a virtual directory and it works.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Fiddler to see where the request for the image is being sent to then make 100% sure that the image is there.
HTH, Benjamin

Comment: I don't see my request but I don't know why.